# Include the bytecode of a JAR file in a gradle library vs. just adding it as a dependency

Tags: maven, gradle

If I add a JAR file to a gradle project's depenencies, the code compiles just fine, but after publishing to maven (publishToMavenLocal), the classes from the JAR are not found.

Obviously, this is because the jar is added as a "dependency" and not part of the project itself. Is there a way to get the contents of the JAR file to merge into the library? Do I need to make a separate maven repo for each JAR?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to create a fat jar which includes dependencies. You can follow the instructions provided here https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Comment: The goal is to create a maven repository, not to create a JAR file. The fat jar would include too many dependencies to upload to maven. Maybe gradle just isn't the tool to do this.